# Civimail 'Dedupe by email': Add Activity 'Bulk email' to all contacts (with same e-mail address) not just to 1

Tags: civimail, duplicate-contacts

An e-mail address is used by 3 contacts. These contacts belongs to a group.
Sending a mail by Civimail to the  group and tick 'Dedupe by email' works fine: only 1 mail is sent. But only 1 contact (randomly?) gets the Activity 'Bulk Email'. Is it possible that all contacts get this Activity?

Comment: possible in the sense of 'out of the box'? no. possible in the sense that 'can an extension be built to add this feature'? probably yes. possible in the sense that 'might the great gods of civicrm bestow this feature on to the community', pretty unlikely tbh.

Comment: Pete's wonderful and eloquent comment in other words: you have to code this yourself. But as you can imagine, it's not too simple and maybe costly. You would hook into the sending process, check for contacts which have the same email address and are in a group addressed by the mailing, get the activity and save a copy.